Laravel Auth Session Text
simple and easy question from a newbie...
I have a new setup of laravel11 and implemented the login and registration function with verifyMail from the documentation.
Everything works fine. I also can use the "forgot password" link and the mail works and everything fine.
But: when I click the "forgot password" link and use the form to send the mail... there is a message calles "password.sent" ... this is the status from the auth-session-status blade
How can I change this "text" and why is there just a "passwort.sent" text as default?
Same is with the error message "auth.failed".

Edit your question and share the code in text format not in image format, and then points out what you did and what do you want to achieve?

Those are translatable messages, but since Laravel 11 they aren't published by default.
More about localization and translation here
Publish the default language files with the following command:
php artisan lang:publish

Now there should be a folder with the default translations (lang/en/..).
The password.sent should be the sent in password.php

We have emailed your password reset link.

The auth.failed shoud be the failed in auth.php

These credentials do not match our records.


Thank you, that solved myProblem... I already switched the language of the page and now created a new folder with the ne language tag and it works!°
